# jquery get Element Text

Tags: jquery, html

i have a small list

like

```
<div class="d1">
<ul>
<li class="active">hello</li>
<li>foo</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="d2">
<ul>
<li class="active">foo</li>
<li>foo</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="d3">
<ul>
<li class="active">bar</li>
<li>foo</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and now i want to get an array with , in this example the size 2 
[0] -> hello
[1] -> foo

but i only want to get all 'active' marked values from div d1, d2 . but coult not find how to access the value.

I think it must be somethink like

```
$('#d1,#d2 li').value
```

but it didnt work :-/

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".d1, .d2").find("li.active").map(function(i, e) { return $(e).text(); })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
var array = new Array();
$('.d1 li.active, .d2 li.active').each(function(){
    array.push($(this).text())
});
```

Comment: with one div it works... but with the d1,d2 wont work :-/ then the full div d1 is now active ..

Comment: i think the problem is the selector. he didnt understand that i need the li object from d1 and d2

Comment: The selector is as wrong as in your example. You have to use `.` instead of `#` as there are no ids in the markup, just classes.

Comment: This won't work for many reasons. There are no `#d1`, `#d2` in the dom. And this isn't what the OP is asking anyway.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Updated the code, which will return an array of the text inside `li` with `active` class in the divs with class `d1` and `d2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var arr = new Array();

$(".d1, .d2").find("li.active").map(function() {
    arr.push( $(this).text() ); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HHSCy/1/)

Comment: This will give all three divs but Roby asked for the first two only.

Answer (score 0):

`d1` and `d2` is class, so you should use `$('.d1,.d2')`, then you find the active li, use `map` to return all the text value of the found li.

```
var ret = $('.d1,.d2').find('li.active').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
});
```